# Partial write()

Tags: c, buffer, stdout

I can't seem to make partial write() work. It goes out of the memory and I don't know why.

```
int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
if(fd == -1) {error handling}

const size_t read_size = 100;
size_t size = read_size;
size_t offset = 0;
size_t res = 0;
char *buff = malloc(size+1);
int lines = 0;
int pos = 0;

while((res = read(fd, buff + offset, read_size)) > 0)
    {
        if(res == -1){error handling}
        offset += res;
        buff[offset] = '\0';
        if (offset + read_size > size)
        {
                size *= 2;
                buff = realloc(buff, size+1);
        }
    }

for(size_t i = 0;buff[i] != '\0'; i++) // counting the buff lines
    {
        if(buff[i] == '\n')
        {
            lines++;
        }
    }

size = read_size;
offset = 0;
res = 0;

if(lines < 10)
{
    while((res = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff+offset, read_size)) > 0)
    {
        offset += res;
    }
}
buff[offset] = '\0';
else{another case where the position is found where the write() needs to start printing}
```

This is a part of a tail implementation in c. There is also another function which handles stdin and does the same thing (this one handles files).

Comment: Partial writes are rare occurrences.  One way it could happen is if you attempt to write 4 KiB of data to a file system that has only 1 KiB of space left.  Other ways are similarly arcane.

Comment: What do you mean by partial write, and what should the code do exactly?

Comment: The whole program is supposed to make the function tail. However a requirement is that I support partial read/write. My program was working perfectly fine with a for loop and printing byte by byte but can't get it to work with partial write(). In the buff is stored either file or stdin data and needs to be printed. So I need to partially write() it to stdout.

Comment: I don't really know how partial writes are supposed to work so I just copied my partial read code and hoped it would work, but unfortunatelly it doesn't.

Comment: Side note: It would be more efficient to move the line `buff[offset] = '\0';` outside the loop.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the posted code. Therefore, I suspect that the problem is in the code that you are not showing us. What are the declared types of the variables? What is the value of these variables when the program reaches the posted code? If possible, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @AndreasWenzel 
    const size_t read_size = 100;
    size_t size = read_size;
    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t res = 0;
    char *buff = malloc(size+1);
I'm pretty sure this part of the code is wrong, because I before I put it in the code it was made with a for loop reading byte by byte and I found no problems in all cases. Since I also use partial read above I do reset  size = read_size;
    offset = 0;
    res = 0; so I can use them again in write().

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But `STDOUT_FILENO` isn't likely a file, it's likely a pipe or tty where partial writes should be expected, especially in a tight loop.

Comment: The posted code is incomplete - without the context in which this code runs, there's really no way anyone can say for certain what's going wrong.  For example, we don't know what `buff`, `res` and `offset` are, and we don't know the value of `offset` or `buff` when the loop starts.  And you seem to be `write()`ing the contents of `buff` as you grow it, but where are the contents you're supposed to be emitting coming from?

Comment: Could it be that you wanted to call `read` instead of `write` and wanted to use `STDIN_FILENO` instead of `STDOUT_FILENO`? It does not make sense to write data from newly allocated memory, because the content of that memory has indeterminate values. However, your posted code would make sense if you were reading instead of writing.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler,  RE "*Partial writes are rare occurrences*", They're easy to produce using a pipe where the producer is faster than the consumer

Comment: Why are you *increasing* the buffer size on a partial write. If anything, it should shrink

Comment: Just updated the code!

Comment: Please describe in words what the second `while` loop is supposed to do? Is it supposed to echo (write back) all the read data, if the number of lines is smaller than `10`? In that case, why are you resizing the buffer in that second `while` loop? This does not make sense.

Comment: Re "*They're easy to produce using a pipe where the producer is faster than the consumer*" ...with a non-blocking handle

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I'm printing the whole buffer and in the other case I get a position and start printing it from there until the end.

Comment: @IliqnGawrilow: If you want to print the contents of a buffer, then you should not resize the buffer while printing it. Resizing the buffer only makes sense when filling the buffer with reads, but not when printing it. Therefore, you should only resize the buffer in the first `while` loop, but not the second `while` loop.

Comment: Ok I removed the whole if and there's still a bit of garbage left. Anything else? It prints 2 extra rows. And also the program doesn't stop running. I need to ctrl+z in the terminal.

Comment: Between filling the buffer with `read` and writing it with `write`, you seem to be using the same `offset` counter, without resetting it in between. Don't you want to save the counter value after finishing reading and then reset it to zero before starting the `write` loop?

Comment: @AndrewHenle — writes to a pipe block by default until the write incomplete or the read end is closed.  Terminals don't do short writes either unless the terminal is disconnected.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel oh yeah i do that idk why it didn't paste in the code here. It still prints garabge if its 0

Comment: I also put "buff[offset] = '\0';" outside the loop because otherwise it gives a Segmenatation error.

Comment: @IliqnGawrilow: Before resetting the counter value `offset` to zero, you should save the value, so that you know how many bytes to print. Also, you should limit the second `while` loop to only print this many bytes.

Comment: So to basically make another condition && it < offset2 and then it++ in the while loop?

Comment: @IliqnGawrilow: Before resetting the `offset` with `offset = 0;`, you should save the number of bytes to write, for example with `size_t to_write = offset;`. Now, instead of writing `while((res = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff+offset, read_size)) > 0)`, you should write `while( to_write > 0 )`, and move the call to `write` inside the loop. See the existing answer on how you could write the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

This is what it might look like:

```c
// Returns 0 on success.
// Returns -1 and sets errno on error.
int write_full(int fd, void *a_buf, size_t count) {
   const char *buf = (char *)a_buf;

   while ( count > 0 ) {
      ssize_t chunk_size = write(fd, buf, count);
      if ( chunk_size < 0 )
         return -1;

      buf   += chunk_size;
      count -= chunk_size;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Testing is tricky. I've only been able to generate a partial write when using a non-blocking handle writing to a pipe with a blocked consumer.

But that results in error `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` so if we temporarily add code to immediately try again (which would be bad to do in practice), we can see the partial writes working.

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Returns 0 on success.
// Returns -1 and sets errno on error.
int write_full(int fd, void *a_buf, size_t count) {
   const char *buf = (char *)a_buf;

   while ( count > 0 ) {
      ssize_t chunk_size = write(fd, buf, count);
      if ( chunk_size < 0 && ( errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK ) ) continue;  // DEBUG
      if ( chunk_size < 0 )
         return -1;

      fprintf(stderr, "Wrote %zd\n", chunk_size);  // DEBUG
      buf   += chunk_size;
      count -= chunk_size;
   }

   return 0;
}

int main(void) {
   int fd = STDOUT_FILENO;
   fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);  // Make non-blocking

   const size_t n = 100000;
   char *buf = malloc(n);
   if (!buf) {
      perror("Can't allocate memory");
      exit(1);
   }

   for (size_t i=n; i--; )
      buf[i] = 'x';

   if ( write_full(fd, buf, n) < 0 ) {
      perror("Write error");
      exit(1);
   }

   free(buf);
   return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic a.c -o a && ./a | perl -e'print while <>' >/dev/null
Wrote 65536
Wrote 8192
Wrote 8192
Wrote 16384
Wrote 1696
```

Perl takes longer to load than the C program allowing the 64 KiB pipe buffer to fill up. You can ensure this bad adding `sleep 2;` to the start  of the Perl program.

Perl reads in 8 KiB chunks, and it takes longer to do so than it takes for the C program to write, so the C program is constantly running out of space in the pipe buffer.

Comment: What is a_buf and to_write?

Comment: The buffer containing the data to write. The number of bytes to write. See the included testing program for an example.

Comment: Just ran the code and the loop doesn't seem to end. I'm writing it to STDOUT_FILENO instead of fd

Comment: `STDOUT_FILENO` is `1`

Comment: It ends with Aborted (core dumped) for me when I run it with gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c11 file.c

Comment: Re "*It ends with free(): invalid pointer and Aborted (core dumped)*", Then you obviously changed something. I can't comment on code I haven't seen.

Comment: Okay I just tried it with a few other files and it seems to print until the count is reached again and doesn't stop so it prints garbage. How can I fix this? For example my count is 100 and a  file is only 1 symbol long and I'm it prints a lot of numbers (I'm guessing 99).

Comment: @IliqnGawrilow how about not telling it to print 100 when you only want to print 1

Comment: *But that results in error EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK so if we temporarily add code to immediately try again (which would be bad to do in practice)*  What? Properly handling `EAGAIN` is "bad practice"?  What about when your call is interrupted by a signal and fails with `errno` set to `EAGAIN`?  Oh wait, most programmers ignore that possibility?!?!  ;-)

Comment: @ikegami but the whole point is to print in chunks. I dont know what the file size would be and how long the lines are.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, Re "*Properly handling EAGAIN is "bad practice"?*", If you think that's the proper way to handle a non-blocking handle, you are clearly mistaken. You'd need to use `select` ///  Re "*What about when your call is interrupted by a signal and fails with errno set to EAGAIN?*", That is not supported. /// Re "*most programmers ignore that possibility*", No, it's a special need that conflict with other special needs. You'd modify the function to your specific special needs if you have some.

Comment: Re "*I dont know what the file size would be and how long the lines are*", Nonsense. If the buffer contains 100 bytes, you pass 100. If the buffer contains 1 byte, you pass 1. It's that simple. This has nothing to do with size of files or length or lines.

Comment: Oh the count is the number of bytes to write. I thought it was the chunk size. But in my case when I'm first reading the file do I need to use my offset from read() to get the amount of bytes I need to write or what? How am I going to get count? Cause otherwise the only thing I have right now is just the chunk size and the buffer itself.

Comment: Re "*Oh the count is the number of bytes to write*", yeah, I literally said it was "The number of bytes to write." /// Re "*when I'm first reading the file*", This has nothing to do with my answer

Comment: Yeah I misread, sorry. But how can I get the count from the read()?

Comment: There is no `read`

Comment: No, from my code in the original question I have a read that saves the file in a buffer and from there how can I get the bytes I need to print (a.k.a count) since I don't have them stored anywhere + I have to read the last 10 lines of the file.

Comment: ...so this is off-topic

Comment: Well not really, I never mentioned I have the number of bytes I need to print I just said I have a buffer that needs to be printed in chunks

Comment: You can't use a buffer if you don't know what's in it. So either you have the size, or what you want to do is impossible. So if you don't have the size, you have a problem to fix. In any case, there's nothing I can change in my answer concerning this.

Comment: @ikegami Brain fart on my part - I meant `EINTR`.  Doh!

Comment: @Andrew Henle, yeah, it could handle `EINTR`, but I'd rather keep the answer focused on the topic rather than lengthening the code to handle a need the OP made no mention of

Comment: Okay, fixed everything. Thanks for your help!